# How to implement Firebase parameterized configuration in TypeScript for Cloud Functions v2?

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables, firebase-tools

I want to use parameterized configuration as [firebase team recommended it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#params), but I can't figure out what is wrong with code below.

```
# .env
# This file is located in functions folder.

LOCATION_FUNCTION=asia-northeast3
```

```js
// index.ts

import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin/app";
initializeApp();

import {defineString} from "firebase-functions/params";
const httpOrCallableFunctionRegion = defineString("LOCATION_FUNCTION");

import {setGlobalOptions} from "firebase-functions/v2";
setGlobalOptions({region: httpOrCallableFunctionRegion});
```

Below is output when I build and run `firebase functions:shell`.

```
/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/npm run shell

> shell
> npm run cleanup && npm run build && firebase functions:shell


> cleanup
> kill-port --port 5001

Could not kill process on port 5001. No process running on port.

> build
> tsc --noImplicitAny --strictNullChecks

✔  functions: Using node@18 from host.
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.
⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Illegal type coercion of param LOCATION_FUNCTION to type string[]
i  functions: Loaded functions: 
No functions emulated.
```

My question is ...

Why the error shows type `string[]`? I really don't know what has to be fixed.

I searched error and code snippets in `firebase-tools` and `firebase-functions` npm packages and other repositories in github, but couldn't figure out it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted firebase team support, and finally found out how to use it.

If you're using Typescript, you may encounter some Illegal type coercion problems. It can be fixed as below.

1. If you're deploying cloud functions on multiple regions

```
// .env
LOCATION_FUNCTIONS=asia-northeast3,us-central1
```

```js
// you must specify type as unknown explicitly
const locafionFunction:unknown = defineList("LOCATION_FUNCTIONS")

export const onHandleRequest = onCall<Request>(
    {
        region: <string[]>locafionFunction, // you should cast as sting[]
    },
    (request: CallableRequest<Request>) => {}
)
```

2. If you're deploying cloud functions on a region

```
// .env
LOCATION_FUNCTION=asia-northeast3
```

```js
// you must specify type as unknown explicitly
const locafionFunction:unknown = defineList("LOCATION_FUNCTION")

export const onHandleRequest = onCall<Request>(
    {
        region: <string[]>locafionFunction, // you should cast as sting[]
    },
    (request: CallableRequest<Request>) => {}
)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this at the global level using Gen 2 Firebase Functions and `setGlobalOptions`? I have asked that question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76711394/type-mismatch-problems-while-setting-region-property-for-gen-2-firebase-function/76712461#76712461).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question: the problem is that `region` expects an array of strings, and you are feeding it with a simple string. Try to spread your param i.e: `region(...httpOrCallableFunctionRegion)`

As for your second question, might be better to open a new thread if you are facing other errors / challenges.

Comment: I guess you're in Cloud functions Gen1, but I'm using Gen 2. And parameter of region is `SupportedRegion | string | Expression<string> | ResetValue` in `GlobalOptions` which is parameter of `setGlobalOptions()`  so I thought it is not sting[] but a string. I deleted second question.